# reference variadic template parameter pack from another template

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, variadic-templates

I have a variadic template class that defines collection of types

```
template <typename ... Types> class TypePack { };
```

Which is instantiated several times

```
typedef TypePack<T1, T2, T3> Pack1;
typedef TypePack<T1, T2, T4> Pack2;
```

I want to reference `TypePack` parameters from other templates

```
template <typename Pack> Client {
    static constexpr std::array<Foo, sizeof...(Pack::Types)> foos {
        make_foo<Pack::Types>()... 
    };
};
typedef Client<Pack1> Client1;
typedef Client<Pack2> Client2;
```

The code above is clearly wrong and doesn't compile. It just serves as illustration of what I would like to achieve.

I could define `Pack1` and `Pack2` through macros but I have a feeling that it should be possible to do it with variadic templates in C++14

Comment: @Barry: Obviously a member, question is whether member data or member function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you're looking for is partial specialization:

```
template <typename Pack> struct Client;

template <class... Ts>
struct Client<TypePack<Ts...>>
{
    static constexpr std::array<Foo, sizeof...(Ts)> foos {{ 
        make_foo<Ts>()...
    }};
};

// don't forget the definition
template <class... Ts>
constexpr std::array<Foo, sizeof...(Ts)> Client<TypePack<Ts...>>::foos;
```

Comment: @T.C. What, you mean functions need *names* now? C++ is so demanding.

Comment: I think the question meant to define a data member, not a function.  With the missing *declarator-id* it is hard to tell, but the absence of the `return` keyword, and presence of a following semicolon which a member function should not have, strongly leans in favor of the braces being a brace-or-equal-initializer and not a function body.